# Async controller/page timeouts .NET MVC 6 (vNext).

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Currently I'm trying to implement a longer page timeout (due to a rather large file upload) in MVC 6 in an Async controller and it seems the trusty ol' `[AsyncTimeout]` attribute does not exist any more in vNext.

I've scoured the net for answers on this and found nothing so far, has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the feature was canned until a latter date due to some issues, see the discussion on the [MVC repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/2083)

Comment: Eek, so there's absolutely no way to do this in .NET Core?! Sounds crazy to me!

Comment: Yep there are some things which won't make it into 1.0, that many would consider to be crucial. However, as MS have stated, they would rather do a 1.0 release with rock solid foundations and some missing features, then release all the features for 1.0 with lots of issues. You may be able to implement your own version for the time being, based off of that pull request, or alternatively, if you are planing on hosting in IIS, you may be able to use the global server timeouts as an override, although I have no idea if that would actually work in this case.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, surprising that people of the community aren't shouting and screaming for this to be fair! Thanks for your time to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

Its not ideal, but you can deal with this issue by increasing the timeout globally on the httpHandler config. Obviously this is only for hosting in IIS.

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="00:05:00" />
```

Comment: Cheers Tom, I'll give this a try!